# group by field for specific values

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sqlplus

How do we use group by only to consider a certain value of a column

eg

if the column has values like , and I only want to group the records with the merge_ind = 'Y' or null, if it is say N the record should be treated as separate value

```
Merge1  Merge2  
A   Y  
A   Y  
A   Y  
B   Y  
B   Y  
B   Y    
C   N  
C   N  
C   N  
D   N  
D   N  
E   null  
E   null  
F   null  
F   null  
null    null
```

the o/p should be

```
count   Merge1  merge2  
3   A   Y   
3   B   Y  
1   C   N  
1   C   N  
1   C   N  
1   D   N  
1   D   N  
2   E   null  
1   F   null  
1   null    null
```

I implemented it using a union but am not very happy with the performance.

Thanks
Ali

Comment: Why is F, null count 1? The input is the same for E, which has output 2

Answer (score 3):

you can do something like this:

```
SQL>  with data as (select 'A' Merge1, 'Y' Merge2 from dual union all
  2  select 'A', 'Y' from dual union all
  3  select 'A', 'Y' from dual union all
  4  select 'B', 'Y' from dual union all
  5  select 'B', 'Y' from dual union all
  6  select 'B', 'Y' from dual union all
  7  select 'C', 'N' from dual union all
  8  select 'C', 'N' from dual union all
  9  select 'C', 'N' from dual union all
 10  select 'D', 'N' from dual union all
 11  select 'D', 'N' from dual union all
 12  select 'E', null from dual union all
 13  select 'E', null from dual union all
 14  select 'F', null from dual union all
 15  select 'F', null from dual union all
 16  select null, null from dual)
 17  select merge1, max(merge2), count(*)
 18    from (select merge1, merge2,
 19                 case when merge2 = 'Y' or merge2 is null then merge2 else to_char(rownum) end grp
 20            from data)
 21   group by merge1, grp
 22   order by merge1;

M M   COUNT(*)
- - ----------
A Y          3
B Y          3
C N          1
C N          1
C N          1
D N          1
D N          1
E            2
F            2
             1
```

test fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b85cc/1

Answer (score 1):

After some considerable mucking around, I have a query that does the job although I could swear this question was originally tagged mysql, and unfortunately this is a mysql only answer:

```
select count, merge1, merge2
from (
  select count(*) count, merge1, merge2,
  if(merge2 = 'Y' or merge2 is null, 0, n)
  from (
    select merge1, merge2,
    (@n := if(@n is null, 1, @n + 1)) n
    from t
  ) x
  group by 2, 3, 4
) y
```

Values not Y are treated as separate values with their own group.

It works by assigning a unique number to each row, them selectively grouping by that too when the value is not Y, thus creating a separate group for each non-Y row.

Here's an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48840/14) with this query running your dara.

Comment: Think you've missed that the OP wants multiple results with C/N and D/N, each with 'count' of 1; and a real count for A/Y and B/Y.

Comment: This should work if you set `null` in Merge2 for the records you don't want to merge.

Comment: @AlexPoole quite so. I have finally figured it out - see edit

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select Merge1, Merge2, count(*)
from table1
group by Merge1, Merge2, case when Merge2 = 'N' then to_char(rownum) else Merge2 end
order by Merge1
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bf62d/11)